# Flattening a multidimensional array with some empty child keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array (note "Cap3"):

```
$myarray = array(
"Cap1" => array(
    "Sub11" => 1 , 
) ,
"Cap2" => array(
    "Sub21" => 2 ,
    "sub22" => 3 ,
) ,
"Cap3" => array(
    4
) , 
"Cap4" => array(
    "Sub41" => 5 ,
) ,
) ;
```

For Cap 1,2,4 array_walk_recursive works perfectly. But I have a problem with Cap3. There I get with 0 => 4. But I would like to get the follwoing array:

```
$result = array(
    "Sub11" => 1 , 
    "Sub21" => 2 ,
    "sub22" => 3 ,
    "Cap3" => 4 , 
    "Sub41" => 5 ,
) ;
```

Any idea how I can get this? Unluckily I cannot change the input array.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:-

```
$result =[];
foreach($myarray as $key=>$val){

        foreach($val as $k => $v){
            if($k !== 0){                   
                $result[$k] = $v;
            }else{                  
                $result[$key] = $v;
            }
        }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [Sub11] => 1
    [Sub21] => 2
    [sub22] => 3
    [Cap3] => 4
    [Sub41] => 5
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Works like a charm.

Comment: @cyberjoe123: You are welcome. Please upvote the answer ;)